# How to change SAMBA default port on centos?

Tags: linux, centos, samba

I need to change the port numbers of samba. Our ISP is blocking the ports 445 and 139. So I need to run samba in a different port.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit `smb.conf` and find a line like this,

`smb ports = 445 139`

change this default port to

`smb ports = 2222 2000`

Then restart samba server. 
Now samba server should be listening on the new ports that you have mentioned.

For more info on customizing samba server click  [here](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html) for documentation.

N.B. : Use port number above 1024 as these are reserved for system purpose.