# Connect samba with Active Directory over port 636

Tags: linux, debian, samba

I'm trying to connect my samba v3 with my Active directory over port 636 for a secure ldap, but every time that a run the command net ads info, the result is over port 389

```
root@articaproxy:~# net ads info
LDAP server: 192.168.0.103
LDAP server name: dc01.abolinhas.home
Realm: ABOLINHAS.HOME
Bind Path: dc=ABOLINHAS,dc=HOME
LDAP port: 389
Server time: Wed, 12 Feb 2020 15:28:40 WET
KDC server: 192.168.0.103
Server time offset: 0
```

My smb.conf

```
[global]
        ldap ssl = start tls
        ldap ssl ads = yes
```

How can i fix it in order the run the net ads over 636?

Answer (score 0):

It's the LDAP port you have to change, not your Samba. Hence if you visit your ldap.conf you will be able to designate the port.

The file is usually in `/etc/ldap/` but the variety of distros do place it in different folders.

https://linux.die.net/man/5/ldap.conf

Comment: I already change the ldap port to 636 but net ads continues to run on port 389

Comment: root@articaproxy:~# net ads info
LDAP server: 192.168.0.103
LDAP server name: dc01.abolinhas.home
Realm: ABOLINHAS.HOME
Bind Path: dc=ABOLINHAS,dc=HOME
LDAP port: 389
Server time: Mon, 02 Mar 2020 22:25:11 WET
KDC server: 192.168.0.103
Server time offset: -1

Comment: Did you try to restart the service after configuration like this https://serverfault.com/questions/583627/best-safest-way-to-stop-and-start-slapd ?
Also check : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104962/how-to-change-samba-default-port-on-centos

Comment: Yes, and i already reboot the server, but net ads continues to run on 389